# When is the d100 roll made for Wild Surge?

Tags: dnd-5e, wild-magic

I am in the process of rolling up a Wild Mage and was looking through the archetype for the rules on when the d100 for the Wild Surge is supposed to be applied. I am not finding much at all.

My question is:

When is the roll supposed to be made, after every spell or only at certain times?

Answer (score 8):

For Wild Magic to trigger, the following have to occur:

1. You have to cast a spell (other than a cantrip)
2. Your DM asks you to roll a Wild Magic Check (d20)*
3. On a 1, roll on the Wild Magic Table

Or, if you have used "Tides of Chaos" since the last long rest:

1. You have to cast a spell (other than a cantrip)
2. Your DM asks you to roll on the Wild Magic table

I believe that having wild magic occur on a spell negates any use of sorcery points, but for the life of me I can't seem to find that anywhere in the PHB or DMG.

Relevant section of the PHB: (pg 103)

> **WILD MAGIC SURGE**
>
> Starting when you choose this origin at 1st level, your spellcasting can unleash surges of untamed magic. *Immediately after you cast a sorcerer spell of 1st level or higher, the DM can have you roll a d20. If you roll a 1, roll on the Wild Magic Surge table to create a random magical effect.*
>
> **TIDES OF CHAOS**
>
> Starting at 1st level, you can manipulate the forces of chance and chaos to gain advantage on one attack roll, ability check, or saving throw. Once you do so you must finish a long rest before you can use this feature again. *Any time before you regain the use of this feature, the DM can have you roll on the Wild Magic Surge table immediately after you cast a sorcerer spell of 1st level or higher.* You then regain the use of this feature.

*this can be a standing rule, or on a per case basis, DM's choice.

Comment: I think it might be worth mentioning that Tides of Chaos does not preclude checking for the surge separately.  You could use Tides of Chaos to gain an advantage on something then cast a level 1 spell, and your DM could have you roll a d20 rather than forcing the surge to happen.  Or he could have you roll the d20 AND roll on the WM surge table, potentially resulting in two surges.